# Is there a way to implement Google Oauth with localhost or any other local url like lvh.me

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

There are many posts about this subject,and all seem to refer to previous versions of Google's API.
How would you go about testing integration on your local dev machine?
localhost or lvh.me or anything similar as the domain.

I have several old integrations, and those ones work well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when I use the Wizard to let Google choose for me what type of credentials/grant I need, and If I choose oauth flow on the server, it will let me use lvh.me as the domain name. But not localhost.
This would not work (for me) when I am trying to do this manually.